# VBA macro toggles NumLock

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp

A funcion is inserting timesatp into the cell with the following code:

```
CrationDate = Now
Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2).Value = CrationDate
```

As I wanted to have it in proper format (so it can be filtered by dates like months and years, and not by values, I added the following:

```
Dim i As String
i = "B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Range(i).Select
SendKeys "{F2}"
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

But the problem is, that function to send {F2} and then {ENTER} keys is also toggling NumLock, which is super annoying. Any ideas why?

Comment: I do nto understand your question. What format is it showing and what format do you want?. SendKeys are highly unreliable. Would not recommend using them. I am sure the issue can be rectified without using Sendkeys. However if using Sendkeys is unavoidable then we can go the API way...

Comment: If manually pressing `F2-Enter` does the job then all you need to do is replace `.Value` in `Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2).Value = CrationDate` with `.Formula` so the line becomes `Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2).Formula = CrationDate`

Answer (score 0):

use [`NumberFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat) property of `Range` object

```
With Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2)
    .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm"
    .Value = Now
End With
```

Comment: @user2602342, any feedback? While hoping the brave masked downvoter enlighten us with his wisdom and knowledge and help me enhance the answer

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but I'd suggest you change the number format first. If it was set to Text, you'd still end up with a text value otherwise.

Comment: @Rory, thank for the comment, but in my test a previously "text" formatted dell behaves in the same manner

Comment: I also did not downvote but I am guessing the reason why anyone would downvote this is because your post does not have an explanation as to to what it does :) BTW I agree with @Rory. If the cell is already formatted as text then do this `.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm"` and then `.Formula = Now` instead of `.Value` which is the same as `F2-Enter`

Comment: @DisplayName I find that unlikely. It certainly doesn't work in any version of Excel I have. The cell contents are still text and it doesn't matter what number format you apply (yours happen to match what VBA would put in the cell as text by default, so try changing the `numberformat` string to something else)

Comment: @Rory, after my macro run the previously "Text" formatted cell becomes "Custom"

Comment: @SiddharthRout, as for the format issue see previous comment

Comment: Yup I have seen it. When you run the code, how is the text aligned? Is it left aligned or right aligned?

Comment: @DisplayName yes, the cell format changes but the contents of the cell are still Text. Try using `.NumberFormat = "0"` in your code and I bet you still see what looks like a date.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, left aligned

Comment: @Rory, yes and its cell format becomes "Number". But in both cases `IsNumber()` excel function returns `False`

Comment: @DisplayName Exactly! It's text, not a date. If it were an actual date, setting the format to Number should show a number (the number of days since 31/12/1899), not a date.

Comment: @Rory, I see it now. Thanks

Comment: In any case that wouldn't be the same behavior of SendKeys "{F2}" + SendKeys "{ENTER}"

Comment: If you follow what i said then it would mimic `SendKeys "{F2}" + SendKeys "{ENTER}"` i.e using `.Formula` instead of `.Value` after setting the numberformat :)

Comment: I was meaning that following the steps 1) pre-setting a cell format as text in excel UI and leaving it selected 2) setting `ActiveCell.Value=Now` through Immediate Window 3) back in excel UI and pressing F2 4) staying in excel UI and pressing Enter -> is leaving me with a text and not a number